# Do two consecutive labels form two different basic block or are they the same in assembly

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, label

I'm stuck on a problem about basic blocks

If we have assembly as such

```
lea random, eax
label1
label2
mov $5, ebx
```

are basic blocks organized like this:

```
lea random, eax
-----------------
label1:
label2:
mov $5, ebx
```

or like this:

```
lea random, eax
----------------
label1:
----------------
label2:
mov $5, ebx
```

Because as I understand it, a basic block is a block of code that executes without breaks, thus doesn't have a label or a jump in the middle of it, only possibly at the ends, but if we have 2 consecutive labels, are they technically not pointing to the same address and thus not different "operations" and fall into the same block?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on your definition of basic block.  I'd say that each label starts a new basic block, even if it's right after another label.  Of course, either label can be eliminated, but as long as it's there, it starts a new block.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense I guess, thank you kind stranger.

Comment: If the label is not a branch target, then it doesn't start a basic block.  You can put labels anywhere (including data), but if you don't actually branch to it from anywhere, it's not a BB.  You might just take its address for some purpose other than (eventually) jumping there, like as an anchor to calculate other locations relative to it.

Comment: IMO an empty basic block doesn't really exist; if you want to think of it as existing and immediately falling through to the next BB, then sure.  If you're writing a compiler, then it's an optimization / simplification waiting to happen in your control-flow graph.

Comment: @Peter: These comments are really waiting to be made into an answer. It's a well-formed question, IMHO. Answering it and having the answer accepted will avoid other potential responders being distracted by the question.

Comment: @rici: fair point, done.  I thought an answer required a little more meat than those comments, so I didn't just repost them right away.

Answer (score 3):

Any label that's a branch target *can* be considered the start of a basic block.

It doesn't really matter whether you look at it as falling through an empty basic block before getting to the "real" one, or whether you decide that both labels are on the same basic block.  Do whichever is convenient.  Both interpretations are perfectly valid.

**But IMO the latter is more logical: an empty basic block doesn't really exist.**  If you're writing a compiler, an empty BB is an optimization / simplification waiting to happen in your control-flow graph.  But not one that's necessary for correctness.  But if reverse-engineering from asm back to a control-flow graph, adding an extra empty node is unnecessary complexity.

---

If the label is not a branch target, then it doesn't start a basic block.

You can put labels anywhere (including data), but if you don't actually branch to it from anywhere, it's not a BB. You might just take its address for some purpose other than (eventually) jumping there, like as an anchor to calculate other locations relative to it.

If you think you have 2 BBs consecutive, but never actually jump to the label on the start of the 2nd, then effectively you have 1 larger BB.  This is a generalization of the point about not introducing extra complexity into your CFG when reversing from asm to program logic.